# AWS Lambda と LINEの接続

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

お世話になっております。

現在、AWS LambdaとLINEを利用して下記のことを実装したいと考えております。

１．LINE@の友達ユーザからメッセージ送信
２．Lambdaで処理したメッセージを返却
３．１の友達ユーザにメッセージを送信

しかし、LINE developersのWebhook URLのVERIFYボタンを押下すると、下記のエラーになります。

「A http status of the response was '502 Bad Gateway'.」

下記のサイトを参考にして、Lambdaの関数作成、LINEの設定を行っております。
http://www.kazuweb.asia/aws/lambda/chatbot

何か、AWSでの設定が追加で必要など、心当たりがございましたら、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決致しました。

LINEにはstatusCode:200を返却する必要があるようなので、処理終了時に下記を追加しました。

```
callback(null, {statusCode:200});
```

LINE developersからVerifyボタンを押下すると、successになりました。